# What are some good algorithms for anomaly detection for time series data?

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

I am aware of Twitter's model, Azure's Anomaly Detection API, Linkedin Luminol. What will be a better alternative for all these methods? Since the data is unlabelled, we cant go for classification methods.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: what kinds of data and application do you have?